# Xamarin Android Scale Bitmap in XML

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to scale a Bitmap in android XML
i have z ordered bitmap inside a layer-list
i have tried to use android:width and heigth but it doesn't work 
in the Designer view in VS2015 it shows correctly but if i deploy the image is scaled to the orginal size.

### XML Layout

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
  <item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/eye2"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:tileMode="disabled"
        android:width="40dp"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="20dp" />
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed:: Just resize the icon png by itselfs.